# detect shutdown in window service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

i have a windows service that get user details and save the result into log text file. and, my problem is when i shut down or log off my system, i also would like to save the time that i down my system into that log file. but, i don't know how to do that.

I checked the winproc method to detect shutdown operation but i was not able to use it on window service, on googling  found it can be used with forms only. how can we detect user have clicked shutdown or log off and do some action. 
so,please give me some idea or suggestion on that.

i have used it for logoff but on log entry is made when i logoff the system

```
  protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
  {
     this.RequestAdditionalTime(250000); //gives a 25 second delay on Logoff
     if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionLogoff)
     {
        // Add your save code here
        StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("D:\\Log.txt", true);
        str.WriteLine("Service stoped due to " + changeDescription.Reason.ToString() + "on" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        str.Close();
     }
     base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
 }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For a shutdown, override the OnShutdown method:

```
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    //your code here
    base.OnShutdown();
}
```

For a logoff:

First, add an event handler to Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded in the Service Constructor:

```
public MyService()
{
    InitializeComponent;
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded);
}
```

Then add the handler:

```
void SystemEvents_SessionEnded(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```

This should catch any ended session, including the console itself (the one running the services).

Comment: Which OS is this? if Vista & Win7 then it is expected behavior as Services are started in Session 0 and any user logon would start another session. [Check here for details](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx)

Comment: The logoff will not fire in the windows service, you need to have the message pump running which you can get by adding a hidden form to your console app

Comment: Does not work in Windows 10 or server 2012/2016. None of the events are fired. Even adding a message pump still does not trigger the events.

Comment: @jjxtra Windows 10 has an option called fast startup which does not call `OnShutdown`. [Check here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783761/2923208)

Answer (score 15):

### Tl;dr

In your service set

```cs
CanShutdown = true;
```

then override

```cs
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    //Your code here

    //Don't forget to call ServiceBase OnShutdown()
    base.OnShutdown();
}
```

---

### Now the extended answer

I know I'm bringing this up from the dead but I found it helpful and hope to add a little to the topic. I'm implementing a WCF duplex library hosted in a Windows Service and came across this thread because I needed to detect, from within the windows service, when a user logs off or shuts down the computer. I'm using .Net Framework 4.6.1 on Windows 7 and Windows 10. Like previously suggested for shutdown what worked for me was overriding `ServiceBase.OnShutdown()` like so:

```
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    //Your code here

    //Don't forget to call ServiceBase OnShutdown()
    base.OnShutdown();
}
```

Remember to add the following to your service's constructor to allow the shutdown event to be caught:

```
CanShutdown = true;
```

Then to capture when a user logs off, locks the screen, switches user, etc. you can just override the `OnSessionChange` method like so:

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{
    if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionLogoff)
    {
        //Your code here...

        //I called a static method in my WCF inbound interface class to do stuff...
    }

    //Don't forget to call ServiceBase OnSessionChange()
    base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
}
```

And of course remember to add the following to your service's constructor to allow catching of session change events:

```
CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
```

Comment: Neither of these are called for me. Set both properties, implemented both functions, attach debugger. Code is not run.

Comment: @jjxtra Windows 10 has an option called fast startup which does not call `OnShutdown`. [Check here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783761/2923208)

Answer (score 4):

You should override [`OnShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onshutdown.aspx) in your service

```
// When system shuts down
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    // Add your save code here
    base.OnShutdown();
}
```

You might also want to override [`OnStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop.aspx)

```
// When the user presses stops your service from the control panel
protected override void OnStop()
{
    // Add your save code here too
    base.OnStop();
}
```

**Edit:**
If you really want to listen to the shutdown event [`Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx) is the way to go.

Comment: @deepu, you are given a reasonable time (I think 30 seconds) to save your state, if that is not enough you can call [`RequestAddtionalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

### Disclaimer

Maybe this answer wont be useful when Windows changes the **Shut down** behavior **again**.

### Which notifications occur when computer Shutsdown?

As far as i was able to find out, three notifications occur when the computer shuts down:

- `SessionLogoff`
- `SessionLock`
- `Suspend`

The first two are delivered by `OnSessionChange()`, and the last by `OnPowerEvent()`.

Of course, a natural choice is `Suspend`, but care should be taken that this notification is also sent when the computer is sent to **Sleep**.

### How to get notified?

To get the notifications posted above you have to allow the notifications in the service constructor as follows:

```cs
public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
    CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
}
```

and then override the respective

```cs
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{
    // Do something
    base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
}

protected override bool OnPowerEvent(PowerBroadcastStatus powerStatus)
{
    // Do something
    return base.OnPowerEvent(powerStatus);
}
```

### What about ServiceBase.OnShutdown()?

Well, this is not called when a computer is *shut down* by clicking on "Shut down" in the Power options.

Indeed, as written in [this official post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011287/windows-updates-not-install-with-fast-startup),

> When you shut down your computer, your computer actually enters a hibernation state instead of a full shutdown.

and further, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onshutdown?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks):

> Use OnShutdown to specify the processing that occurs when the system shuts down.
>
> **This event occurs only when the operating system is shut down, not when the computer is turned off.**
>
> OnShutdown is expected to be overridden when the CanShutdown property is true.

So, if manually shutting down the computer does not really shuts down the computer, but it puts it in an hibernation state, what can shut down the computer?

The [post quoted above](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011287/windows-updates-not-install-with-fast-startup) has again the answer:

> Full shutdown only occurs when you restart a computer or when other event causes the computer to process a full shutdown.

And indeed, i could get the `OnShutdown()` method called on my service by setting

```
CanShutdown = true;
```

and overriding to OnShutdown

```
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    // Do something
    base.OnShutdown();
}
```

and then restarting my computer.

---

Well, enough with this post. I only hope the shut down behavior of Windows does not change soon...

Comment: It should be the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35774814/detect-if-shutdown-in-progress.aspx).  Poll the method in question every now and then (1 second interval) and you'll be able to do what you want.

You need [RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call.