# How get system start up event in windows service c#?

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services, systemevent

I am writing a windows service. I want to do some functions on system start up, system lock, shutdown. How to get the start up,lock and shutdown events in the windows service ?

Comment: As a startingpoint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202119/detect-shutdown-in-window-service  With regard to StartUp: How would that be different from your service being started in the first place? You can't subscribe to events from a systen that is not started.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents class.