# Windows Service log writing on system shutdown / restart

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-services

The issue is that when host machine is restarted (Windows restart) or shutdown (Windows shutdown) nothing is being written to the log.

I have the following in a Windows Service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    eventLogUtility.WriteToEventLog("Service has Started.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    eventLogUtility.WriteToEventLog("Service has Stopped.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}

/// <summary>When implemented in a derived class, executes when the system is shutting down.
/// Specifies what should occur immediately prior to the system shutting down.</summary>
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    eventLogUtility.WriteToEventLog("Service has Shutdown.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

- When the service starts, "Service has Started." is written to the log.
- When the service is stopped by me, "Service has Stopped." is written to the log.

P.S. Using .Net 4.5

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as I'm not a services guy, but I don't think `OnShutdown` always covers restarts. Try the `SessionEnded` method instead [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202119/detect-shutdown-in-window-service).

Comment: @Equalsk Thanks for your help but I forgot to put in the question text that it isn't just restart... shutdown also does not work... I've edited it now... the title did say shutdown / restart

Comment: Hmm... testing... it looks like it could be due to which account it is running under... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b7d82c3-e7d6-471f-b085-d46e7de9c737/service-not-doing-onstop-or-onshutdown-when-windows-shuts-down?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Nope that made no difference... still not writing to log using an (domain) admin account, logging on as system or logging on as service... nothing is written. grrrr

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because [Windows Event Log](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd315601(v=ws.10).aspx) service shutdowns before your service. 
You can solve it by making your Service depends on `Windows Event Log` using [ServiceInstaller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
 ...
 ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller()
 serviceInstaller.ServicesDependedOn = new string [] { "EventLog" };
 ...
```

or with the visual editor by adding "*EventLog*" :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already use ServiceInstaller so I just added 'EventLog' to ServiceDependedOn, installed the service on my dev machine, shutdown windows... and nothing is written to the event log :S ... Documentation implies it's all about service dependencies required for the service to start... nothing about shutting down etc.

Comment: Just making sure... is EventLog the name of the windows event log service? or a generic name? or is it supposed to be the name of my instance of Event Log ?

Comment: It should be. Have you checked in the dependecies tab on your service properties to see if Windows Event log is there ?

Comment: It should be... It should be what?... I manually put EventLog using the visual editor.

Comment: Ah k thx, just checked the service entry using Computer Management and it says, just as your image, Windows Event Log as a dependency... alas still not working.

Comment: It also doesn't work for me.