# PowerShell : intercept Windows shutdown and prevent shutdown

Tags: powershell, listener, shutdown

I have a Powershell script that runs a process undefinitely.

I want it to perform a few commands before the PC's shutdown.

Here is the process I would like :

1. User clicks shutdown button
2. Windows shows the black screen
3. Windows displays my script as 'preventing shutdown'
4. The script receives a signal saying the system has to shut down
5. The script runs a few commands and then exits
6. Windows detects nothing is preventing shutdown ans shuts down

Would that be possible ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Look up GPOs, there's an option for shutdown / logoff scripts instead.

Comment: @vonPryz thanks, but can a shutdown script interact with another currently-running script ? if so, how, can the main script receive the signal from the GPO ?

Comment: You should [edit] the question itself and explain with more details what you are trying to [achieve](https://xyproblem.info/). Some kind of IPC is needed, what would do depends on the actual problem.

Comment: It sounds like you'll want to implement a [Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202119/detect-shutdown-in-window-service) to host your PowerShell script...